# select fields with Javascript object

Tags: javascript, object, select

I'm hoping to populate a select field with color options. So far I have this:

```
 function getFruit() {
 var x = document.getElementById("myinput").value;
 var score;
 var picture;
 if (x === "Apple") {
 score = "A";
 picture = "http://exampple.com/assets/apple.jpg";
 }
else if (x === "Banana") {
score = "B";
picture = "http://example.com/assets/banana.jpg";
}
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = score;
document.getElementById("display").image.src = picture;
```

}

```
<input type="text" id="text">
<img id="display" />
<select id="color"></color>
```

but I would like to populate a select field with color options, something like:

```
if (x === "Apple") {
 score = "A";
 picture = "http://exampple.com/assets/apple.jpg";
 color = "Red" "Green" Blue";
 }
```

Any ideas what format I need to use to add this?

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of `colors` along with the function `add`:

```
.add(new Option(c, value));
```

```js
var colors = ["Red", "Green", "Blue"];
var sel = document.getElementById('color');

colors.forEach((c, value/*This is the index of this loop*/) => sel.add(new Option(c, value)));
```

```html
<select id="color"></select>
```

Comment: Why did you select it with `querySelector('select')`? That makes no sense since it conveniently has an ID, simply use `getElementById('color')`.

Comment: @RacilHilan you're right, I didn't realize. Updated!

Answer (score 0):

After

```
if(x === "Apple") {
    score = "A";
    picture = "http://exampple.com/assets/apple.jpg";
    colors = ["Red", "Green", Blue"];
 }
```

use the reduce method to generate a string of options and assign it to the inner html of color select-box.

```
document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = color.map((color) => '<option value="' + color+ '">' +color +'</option>').join();
```

http://jsbin.com/kuyazekivu/edit?html,js,console,output